# JSON to String in python

Tags: python, string

there is part in my project using python where I get a JSON object and get those values and convert them to string.

My input will be:

```
data = {
        "date":'12.04.2019',
        "time":'06 am',
        "event":'Complete project'
        }
```

My output should be:

```
On 12.04.2019, 06 am the reminder is to Complete project
```

I have tried different methods to convert the JSON values to String but I get some sort of errors.

Comment: What sort of errors? What did you try?

Comment: `print('On ' + data['date']+', '+data['time']+' the reminder is to '+data['event'])` should do it !

Comment: It's not actually even JSON, that's a dictionary

Comment: @roganjosh, In MongoDB, JSON file structure is used and I have assigned resulting data from the DB to a local variable 'data'

Comment: Thanks @pistol2myhead it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this's not a Json object, this is a dictionary so you can direct access the keys in it i.e.

```
res="On "+str(data['date'])+", "+str(data['time'])+"the reminder is to"+str(data['event'])
print(res)
```

you can also use date.get('date') to get the value of a specific key,they're both the same

for more info about dictionaries :https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

for more info about Json Objects: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: Please, please, please don't use `w3schools` as a resource. There is just way too much garbage there :/

Comment: ["Here's all the info about python arrays, which it doesn't have (but actually it does), but we'll call them arrays anyway when we actually mean lists"](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) horrible site.

Comment: Yeah, just _avoid_ that site. It's nonsense.

Comment: Roger that, I'll avoid it in my next answers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.6 you can use f strings:

```
print(f"On {data['date']}, {data['time']} the reminder is to {data['event']}")
```

If you don't have python 3.6 or above I suggest you to use formatting:

```
print("On %s, %s the reminder is to %s" %(data['date'], data['time'], data['event']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a JSON object it is a `dictionary`, so you can extract data using a keys.

Sample code:

```
data = {
        "date":'12.04.2019',
        "time":'06 am',
        "event":'Complete project'
        }

print("On "+ data["date"]+","+ data["time"] +" the reminder is to "+ data["event"])
```

Output:

```
On 12.04.2019,06 am the reminder is to Complete project
```